# Python PYODBC with OpenJson Issue

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to run the following code in my Python script and it is failing with syntax errors I've not been able top correct. The first insert brings in json data from a web site and works perfectly. The second insert statement formats the json code and puts it in another SQL Table. This code works fine in MSSQL. The second insert refers to missing closing quote but I seem to have an opening and closing quote. It also refers to an unresolved reference openjson and unresolved reference cross apply. I've tried putting opening/closing brackets around both the insert and select statements but no luck. I looked through the pyodbc wiki on github but didn't see a similar example. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

````
cursor.execute("Insert Into InboundJson (json) values (?)", (json.dumps(response_json),))
conn.commit()  -- works fine

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Insert into [CCSBC-DW1].[SurveyMonkey].[dbo].Surveylist (SurveyId, Description, WebSite)

Select J_open.*
from
  dbo.InboundJson j
  cross apply
  openjson(j.[json], '$.data') with ( id          int ,
                                      title  varchar(200),

                                      href    varchar(200)) j_open;")
conn.commit()```
````

Comment: T-SQL statement is correct (of course, the stored JSON must have 'data' key), but you need to use SQL Server 2016+.

Comment: The Server is SQL 2019 and it works fine there. The problem is the Python syntax I am using.

Comment: This code is not compilable in Python. Please post exact error you receive. You should be receiving a SyntaxError before any pyodbc error.

Comment: When I run this, I am getting the following:

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning  string literal

Comment: cursor.execute("Insert into [DBPath] (Id,Description,Website) . It seems to want a double quote at the end of the Insert but I am using  the Select statement to get the content. I think the issue is the placement of the double quotes. I've tried a few different options but haven't got this to work as yet via Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use triple-quoted enclosures for multi-line string:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO [CCSBC-DW1].[SurveyMonkey].[dbo].Surveylist (SurveyId, Description, WebSite)
                  SELECT J_open.*
                  FROM dbo.InboundJson j
                  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.[json], '$.data') 
                              WITH (id int,
                                    title varchar(200),
                                    href varchar(200)) j_open;
               """)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks for your help.